# How do I transform this block of code into list comprehension

Tags: python-2.7, list, list-comprehension

I just wanna ask if it's possible to transform this code into a  list comprehension? I'm using python 2.7+

the code looks like this:

```
for x in y:
    if condition1:
        if condition3:
            expression1
        else:
            expression2
    else:
        if condition5:
            expression3
        else:
            expression4
```

So far, I've managed to code like this:

```
c=[expression1 if condition3 else expression2 for x in y if condition1]
```

It runs smoothly but it's incomplete.

My problem is, whenever I add the code from line 7 to 11,  like this:

```
c=[expression1 if condition3 else expression2 for x in y if condition1 else expression3 if condition5 else expression4]
```

It says 'syntax error'. Uhmm. Can you give me some advice? I will appreciate it. Let me know if this question has a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want all the conditions before `for x in y`, and you need to separate the code for the nested if statements with parentheses like this:

```
[(  ...  ) if condition1 else ( ... ) for x in y]
```

So the final comprehension looks like:

```
c=[(expression1 if condition3 else expression2) if condition1 else (expression3 if condition5 else expression4) for x in y]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Trelzevir... :-)